# How to upload or save files to server in flutter?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, dart, flutter-plugin

I am trying to save or upload files with different extensions to server. I have the server path to send the files and the local file path taken using the file picker. Now I have to upload this to server. I am using objective-c to build iOS. How can this possible?

Comment: use [http](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest) library

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a POST request on your path to send the file and completing the body of your request with your file data. (using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package)

Or the package [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader) might help you too.